# Error - PrimeReact Autocomplete suggestions not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, primereact, react-lifecycle-hooks

https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/autocomplete

I am trying to load suggestions dropdown as soon as component loads with some data in `componentDidMount`.  The `suggestionsList` is updating with the `obj` data in `componentDidMount`, however suggestion dropdown is not showing.

Simply, whenever input is get focussed and no input text is there, a suggestion dropdown should show.

## abcCmp.jsx

```
class abcCmp extends React.Component {
      state;
      constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                suggestionsList: []
            };
      }
    
    componentDidMount() {
      let obj = [{'color':'red',name: 'Danny', id: '1'}];
      this.setState({suggestionsList: [...obj]})
    }
    
    render(){
           return (
                <div className="containerBox">
                   <AutoComplete suggestions={this.state.suggestionsList}
                                minLength={1} placeholder="Add People" field="name"  multiple={true}  
                     autoFocus={true} />
                </div>
           )
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you gone through documentation there are other parameters also required.
Those are: `completeMethod`,`value`,`onChange` out of these `completeMethod` is required to show filtered list as you type. Inside `completeMethod` you need to filter your data that's how your dropdown list reduces as you type more.

You need `ref` for toggling dropdown functionality and also you need to check on focus if input value is empty and no value is selected so toggle dropdown.

Here is simple POC I create for reference. Try typing **`D`**

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { AutoComplete } from "primereact/autocomplete";
import "./styles.css";
let obj = [
  { color: "red", name: "Dagny", id: "1" },
  { color: "red", name: "kanny", id: "2" },
  { color: "red", name: "Dgnny", id: "3" },
  { color: "red", name: "Danny", id: "4" },
  { color: "red", name: "Dmnny", id: "5" },
  { color: "red", name: "Donny", id: "" }
];
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  myRef = React.createRef();
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      suggestionsList: [],
      selected: null,
      inputValue: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ suggestionsList: [...obj] });
  }
  searchList = (event) => {
    let suggestionsList;

    if (!event.query.trim().length) {
      suggestionsList = [...obj];
    } else {
      suggestionsList = [...obj].filter((list) => {
        return list.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(event.query.toLowerCase());
      });
    }

    this.setState({ suggestionsList });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="containerBox">
        <AutoComplete
          suggestions={this.state.suggestionsList}
          completeMethod={this.searchList}
          minLength={1}
          ref={this.myRef}
          dropdown
          inputId="my"
          placeholder="Add People"
          field="name"
          onFocus={(e) => {
            if (!this.state.inputValue && !this.state.selected) {
              this.myRef.current.onDropdownClick(e, "");
            }
          }}
          onKeyUp={(e) => this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value })}
          // completeOnFocus={true}
          multiple={true}
          autoFocus={true}
          value={this.state.selected}
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({ selected: e.value })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/prime-react-autocomplete-forked-n3x2x?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The demo is not working. The requirement is whenever input  get focussed and no input text is there, a suggestion dropdown should show with some data.

Comment: Prime react does not provide this functionality. So have to do some change by its self. Updated my answer plz check again

Comment: After adding few chips when we delete those inspite it is focussed and even we focus it again it does not work. Also, after some suggestion is selected (then chips added) and input get focussed and input text length is zero, still the suggestion dropdown not visible.

Comment: That condition you can change on your `onFocus`. It just poc to give you context

Comment: ok, will give it a try. Can we have multiple fields here like field={"name" | "color"}

Comment: this.myRef.current.onDropdownClick(), did the job.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add dropdown inside autocomplete tags and also add completeMethod and bind it to a search/filter function, add a value to bind the selected value, add a onChange function to it
You can find full documantation and working example here :[PrimeFaces React Autocomplete](https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/autocomplete)