# How assign id to PrimeReact AutoComplete component

Tags: primereact

I'm using *PrimeReact* *AutoComplete* component:

```
<AutoComplete
  id='parent-autocomplete'
  value={parent}
  onChange={(e) => setParent(e.value)}
  suggestions={filteredGroups}
  completeMethod={searchGroup}
  field='name'
  dropdown
></AutoComplete>
```

I added an `id` for the component but it doesn't assign it to the input inside the component.

I need this id to check it has a value if it's specified as required.

**How can I add an `id` for the `input` inside the component?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63494712/error-primereact-autocomplete-suggestions-not-showing) but not directly:

To assign id for Autocomplete input field just add this prop:

```
inputId="optional-id"
```